# Magento 2.1.12 - Как добавить iframe на страницу?

Tags: iframe, magento

Magento 2.1.12 - Как добавить iframe на конкретную страницу? Кто знает хоть какой способ? Годится хоть под "танец с бубном"?

Answer (score 0):

Тут все легко и просто , заходишь в папку *magento/app/design/frontend/Твоя_Текущая_Тема/default/template/Название_твоего_модуля/НазваниеФайла.phtml*

или же для добавления на домашнюю страницу :
*Z:\home\localhost\www\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\1column.phtml*
и добавляешь свой айфрейм

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for Mage_Page_Block_Html
 */
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
```

Сюда в конец добавляешь айфрейм, конец кода там такой :

```
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
        <div class="page">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
            <div class="main-container col1-layout">
                <div class="main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```